# how to get EST and UTC irrespective of Day

Tags: sql, oracle, date, dst

I have to show EST/EDT and GMT/UTC using Oracle 10g.The issue is on Nov 2nd UTC difference will change '+ 05' hour which will cause my jobs to fail.Please let me know how to fix it without manually changing interval to 5 hours.I have tried new_time function but that does not solve the problem. The all columns are DATE datatype.

```
SELECT PROCESS_NAME, 
     date_modified as EST_DATE_MODIFIED,
     date_modified + interval '+ 04' hour as GMT_DATE_MODIFIED
FROM tbl_process_status ;
```

Result

```
EST_DATE_MODIFIED    GMT_DATE_MODIFIED
22-OCT-14 11:08:25  22-OCT-14 03:08:25
```

Thanks Ed but above query is not returning correct UTC time.

```
EST - 22-OCT-14 12:19:55
Correct UTC- 22-OCT-14 04:19:55
Above Query UTC 22-OCT-14 08:19:55 

 select (TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'TZH')) * INTERVAL '1' HOUR) from dual;
 -0 4:0:0.0
```

Thanks Multisync. 
I got below result but I need data only in DD-MON-YY HH:MM:SS Format.

```
Expected 22-OCT-14 12:19:55    
Expected 22-OCT-14 04:19:55    
Result   22-OCT-14 12.19.55.000000000 PM AMERICA/NEW_YORK      
Result   22-OCT-14 04.19.55.000000000 PM UTC
```

Comment: Is your `date_modified` a `DATE`, or a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`?

Comment: Date_modified is Date datatype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select systimestamp at time zone 'est' for_timestamp,
       cast(sysdate as timestamp) at time zone 'est' for_date, 
       cast(sysdate as timestamp) at time zone 'gmt' gmt_timezone 
  from dual;
```

So you can try this (edited according to the comments)

```
SELECT PROCESS_NAME, 
     cast(cast(date_modified as timestamp) at time zone 'America/New_York' as date) as EST_DATE_MODIFIED,
     cast(cast(date_modified as timestamp) at time zone 'UTC' as date) as GMT_DATE_MODIFIED
FROM tbl_process_status;
```

Comment: To support daylight saving time (as was asked), you should use `'America/New_York'` instead of `'est'`.  Also, it's more correct to use `'UTC'` instead of `'gmt'`.

Comment: Thanks Multisync. I got below result but I need data only in DD-MON-YY HH:MM:SS Format.  Expected 22-OCT-14 12:19:55 
  Expected 22-OCT-14 04:19:55 
  Result   22-OCT-14 12.19.55.000000000 PM AMERICA/NEW_YORK 
  Result   22-OCT-14 04.19.55.000000000 PM UTC